AWS Systems manager file system unable to preview or download file
I am using AWS Systems manager(SSM) to connect EC2 instances.
I want to preview or download file which is inside EC2 instance but I am unable to do so.

When I click on preview as text or Tail file, I get "An unexpected error occured" without any more info what I am missing. I have checked into diiferenet devices with different connectivity as well but same error.




Similarly when I try to copy and then paste to my local machine it actually does nothing. The button mentions "Local file transfer" then it should transfer file to my local.


Is there any SSM configuration am I missing or is there a way to download file from EC2 instance which is not accessible via SSH?
Note: I have KMS encryption disabled in Session manager-->General preferences.

Checked errors.log and amazon-ssm-agent.log in /var/log/amazon/ssm/ while doing this operation but seems no logs are generating there.

checked cloudtrail logs and getting below response. What to understand from here?
ERROR [submit @ processor.go.327] [ssm-agent-worker] [MessageService] [Association] [associationId=5efsd33b3-928f-4194-bd25-c5edd3237a] Document Submission failed: Job with id 5eff58b3-925f-3194-bd25-c5sfae3907a already exists
